# How can I decrypt data encrypted with CryptoJS using an inadequate size key/iv?

Tags: node.js, aes, cryptojs

I have data that was encrypted with the CryptoJS library, but it was encrypted using AES CBC with a key and an iv which were the same and the wrong size (between 17 and 21 characters). I tried to decrypt them but I only get empty strings, I also tried to fill the keys with padding and I still can't decrypt the data.

I validated that the encryption method with a 16 and 24 character key works fine and can be decrypted without problems but right now I need to be able to decrypt the data that was worked with the wrong size keys..

The encryption function is similar to this:

```
function aesEncryptData(value) {
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("ajMgHj6Vt6vn0dY2Bw");
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("ajMgHj6Vt6vn0dY2Bw");
var valueEncrypted
    valueEncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key,
    {iv: iv,mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    }).toString();
return valueEncrypted;}
```

Comment: *...I need to be able to decrypt the data that was worked with the wrong size keys...*: No chance (more precisely, is only possible with CryptoJS itself). Your Base64 encoded key `ajMgHj6Vt6vn0dY2Bw` has a length of 18 bytes, which corresponds to a raw key length of 13 bytes. The key lengths allowed for AES are 16, 24 and 32 bytes, i.e your key is invalid. However, CryptoJS accepts invalid key lengths (due to a bug, [#293](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293)) and determines a ciphertext which is *not AES compliant*. Hence, any AES compliant decryption will fail.

Comment: @Topaco And how could I do it using CryptoJS, I just need to decrypt this specific data. Is there a setting I can make so that the decrypt function of CryptoJS can work with these keys?

Comment: Decryption should work as for valid keys. I just tested it again, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wvb1k86a/) with the result that decryption with invalid keys *does not seem to be reliable*, e.g. for an invalid key of length 12 bytes it works, but for your invalid key of length 13 bytes it does not work. So I have to qualify my claim: CryptoJS can decrypt the ciphertexts generated with invalid keys only for *some, but not all* invalid key lengths.

Comment: I worked with this for a couple of hours last night. CryptoJS **really** messes up the algorithm when the key-length is too short (the number of rounds isn't just invalid, it's fractional: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/4dcaa7afd08f48cd285463b8f9499cdb242605fa/src/aes.js#L92). I couldn't find any way to make the `invKeySchedule` correct (the piece you'd need in order to decrypt this). I don't know for certain that there *is* a decryption algorithm for this.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/293

Comment: Purely empirical (tested for key sizes between 0 and 64 bytes): For all sizes that are a multiple of 4 bytes, the ciphertext can be decrypted. For all other sizes decryption fails, see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8sckmzw/1/).